# When is having a mutable and an immutable reference at the same time really a problem?

Tags: rust, memory-management

I've been playing around with Rust for some time now. It's hard, it's new, it's exciting, and the compiler is very helpful. So I usually end up with working code. But there is one problem I quite fundamentally do not understand. Which is why having multiple mutable references, or some immutable ones and a mutable one, is a problem?

Firstly, in a sequentially executing program, I don't see how this could *ever* be a problem. Say I have two references, no matter whether mutable or immutable. At any point in time, only one thing will use the reference. Sure, the *value* may change, but I don't see how memory unsafety could arise here.

The only way this could ever be relevant in any way (that I can imagine) is when we introduce multiple threads. I'd be more comfortable knowing for sure that all of them only read the data, because there is no way some other thread can screw with the value while I'm reading it. Is this assumption correct? Is the whole mutability deal only relevant in multi-threaded contexts (other than code predictability that is also found in other languages like `let` and `const` in JS)? If not, how could a sequential program run into trouble (as seen by Rust) because data was mutable when it shouldn't have been?

The second issue seems even more striking: Sure, I can only have one mutable reference at a time, or none while also having immutable references. But there still is the owner of the data! He can mutate it at any time, particularly also while another spawned thread reads the data via an immutable reference (if that is even possible, which I doubt, due to lifetime checks). What kind of safety is added by disallowing mutable references to otherwise referenced data when the owner still keeps the right to mutate the data?

As you can see, these questions are quite fundamental to my understanding of what Rust adds in terms of memory safety in this regard. Unfortunately, I haven't found any explicit explanations to why this is done, only *that*.

Comment: "Mutable" and "immutable" are kind of misnomers in the language - what `mut` and non-`mut` actually mean is "exclusive" and "shared".

Comment: @Finomnis interesting take on the topic, thanks

Comment: "But there still is the owner of the data! He can mutate it at any time" No it can't. To modify the data, even the owner needs a reference to it, either via `&mut self` or just passing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, this trivial Python example can help

```py
def remove_unexpected_element(sequence, unexpected):
    for (idx, elem) in enumerate(sequence):
        if elem == unexpected:
            sequence.pop(idx)

seq = [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30]
remove_unexpected_element(seq, 20)
print(seq) # [10, 10, 20, 30, 30]
```

A programmer aware of the details of how iterating on a sequence works in Python could detect at first sight that this is incorrect.
But if we don't know these details, we don't know if this code does what it seems to do.
Maybe another language could perform this loop as expected...
(Note that Java performs a runtime check, `checkForComodification()`, in order to detect such a situation and throw an exception)
With Rust, we could simply not express such an ambiguous situation because we try to mutate a data (the sequence) while we are **still** consulting it (during **all** the iterations).
If we really want to express such an algorithm, we would have to count explicitly with an integer and access the sequence using indexing.
Instead of a long consultation of the sequence (during the iterations), we would have to perform multiple distinct accesses (check length, remove an element...) and it's our responsibility to keep all of this consistent.
If this does not work as expected, it is because of a bug which is explicitly readable in the source code of our algorithm.

For your second issue, the mutable reference exists simultaneously with the mutable value it refers to, but during the section of code this reference is used, the value cannot directly be accessed.
This is exactly what the borrow-checker takes care of.
When it comes to multi-threading, you won't be able to pass an exclusive (mutable) reference to another thread while still being able to use the original value in its original location without a synchronisation mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that shared, writable memory is *bad*. Rust will try as hard as it can to prevent that situation. Either a pointer to a memory region is *unalised* (that is, no other pointer points to that memory region) or it is not *mutable* (that is, you cannot write to that memory region through that pointer). Although what I just said is an approximation of the model Rust uses, it is enough to understand the motivations behind it.

Take, for instance, the following program written in `C`

```c
void add_twice_1(int *a, int *b) {
    *a += *b;
    *a += *b;
}
```

It takes two pointers to integers, and adds the content of the second one to the first one twice. Now, you might want to think that this program is equivalent to the following one:

```c
void add_twice_2(int *a, int *b) {
    *a += *b * 2;
}
```

However, as is, these two programs are actually *not* the same, if `a` and `b` are the same pointer:

```c
void main() {
    int i = 3;
    add_twice_1(&i, &i);
    // `i` is now 12

    int j = 3;
    add_twice_2(&j, &j);
    // `j` is now 9!
}
```

As you can see, the problem comes from the fact that, when `add_twice_1` is called, the pointer `a` is both used to write to the pointed memory region *and* aliased by `b`.

Now, the reason this is a problem is that compilers are essentially tools that translate the code you write into code the machine runs. An important property that they have to ensure is that these two codes behave the same. To do so, they must be able to reason about programs, and it's much harder to do so with shared mutable pointers (which is also true for humans btw). For instance, if you were to write that code in Rust you would do the following:

```rust
fn add_twice(a: &mut i32, b: &i32) {
    *a += *b;
    *a += *b;
}
```

`a` necessarily is a mutable borrow, and therefore is unaliased, so the Rust compiler is free to optimize this function as I did above (and the other way around).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Both answers I got so far have helped me understand the topic much better. I just personally prefer the other answer, so I'll accept that one. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your explanation, too!